# How to use maven package at so many times

Tags: maven

I used maven assembly plugin to create a zip file for my project. When I do mvn package for the first time, there is no error. But for a second by doing mvn package I notice an error. How to do mvn as many times without error.
    Below my script maven

```
    <!-- Maven assembly plugin -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>frontendArchive</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/zip.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>


    <!--My zip.xml file-->
    <assembly  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
      <id>WebContent</id>
      <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
      </formats>
      <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
      <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
        <directory>WebContent</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
                <include>**/*.zip</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
      </fileSets>
    </assembly>



Here is the error that appears for a second time by doing mvn package

C:\User\Projects\frontendWeb>mvn package

C:\User\Projects\frontendWeb>call "C:\Program Files\myDir\bin\maven3\bin\mvn3" package
Running with Maven 3
MAVEN_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Eclipse_DEV\Jdks\jdk1.8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Portail de services SEPH 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:timestamp-property (get-timestamp-property) @ frontend-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (filter-resources) @ frontend-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 23 resources to C:\User\Projects\frontendWeb\WebContent/resources
[INFO] Copying 6 resources to C:\User\Projects\frontendWeb\WebContent
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:3.0.0:single (frontendArchive) @ frontend-web ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/zip.xml
[ERROR] OS=Windows and the assembly descriptor contains a *nix-specific root-relative-reference (starting with slash) /
[INFO] Building zip: C:\User\Projects\frontendWeb\WebContent\frontend-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.797 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-26T16:54:38+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.0.0:single (frontendArchive) on project frontend-web: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly ar
chive WebContent: A zip file cannot include itself -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

C:\User\Projects\frontendWeb>
```

Comment: Exclude your zip file

Comment: Thanks you Jens your advice is good.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can configuration use in bellow link :-

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/